# Using kryo to custom serialize java object in kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, kryo

I'm trying to send java object using kryo object serializer. I'm running into couple of issues. First, I'm not able to extend kryo to serialize a java bean, which is my payload. Here's the custom serializer.

```
package com.test.kafka.serialization;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.ByteBufferInput;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.ByteBufferOutput;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output;
import com.test.kafka.TextAnalysisRequest;

public class KryoReadingSerializer implements Closeable, AutoCloseable, Serializer, Deserializer {
    private ThreadLocal kryos = new ThreadLocal() {
        protected Kryo initialValue() {
            Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
            kryo.addDefaultSerializer(TextAnalysisRequest.class, new KryoInternalSerializer());
            return kryo;
        };
    };

    @Override
    public void configure(Map map, boolean b) {
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String s, TextAnalysisRequest ta) {
        ByteBufferOutput output = new ByteBufferOutput(100);
        kryos.get().writeObject(output, ta);
        return output.toBytes();
    }

    @Override
    public TextAnalysisRequest deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            return kryos.get().readObject(new ByteBufferInput(bytes), TextAnalysisRequest.class);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error reading bytes",e);
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.io.Closeable#close()
     */
     @Override
     public void close() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

     private static class KryoInternalSerializer extends com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer {
         @Override
         public void write(Kryo kryo, Output output, TextAnalysisRequest ta) {
             System.out.println("Kryo write....");
             kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, ta);
         }

         @Override
         public TextAnalysisRequest read(Kryo kryo, Input input, Class aClass) {
             System.out.println("Kryo read....");
             TextAnalysisRequest ta = null;
             ta = (TextAnalysisRequest)kryo.readClassAndObject(input);
             return ta;
         }
     }
}
```

The publish part is working fine, but it's failing during read.The following error is being thrown at read. It sort of goes on an infinite loop and keeps throwing this exception.

```
 Error -->org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition full-3 at offset 321
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition full-3 at offset 321
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error reading bytes
    at com.test.kafka.serialization.KryoReadingSerializer.deserialize(KryoReadingSerializer.java:55)
    at com.test.kafka.serialization.KryoReadingSerializer.deserialize(KryoReadingSerializer.java:1)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:627)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseFetchedData(Fetcher.java:548)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:354)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1000)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)
    at com.test.kafka.consumer.ConsumerGroupSerializerObject1.run(ConsumerGroupSerializerObject1.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 13994
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:119)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:641)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:752)
    at com.test.kafka.serialization.KryoReadingSerializer$KryoInternalSerializer.read(KryoReadingSerializer.java:102)
    at com.test.kafka.serialization.KryoReadingSerializer$KryoInternalSerializer.read(KryoReadingSerializer.java:1)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:657)
    at com.test.kafka.serialization.KryoReadingSerializer.deserialize(KryoReadingSerializer.java:52)
    ... 12 more
```

Heres's my java object:

```
public class TextAnalysisRequest implements Serializable {
    public String url;
    public String source; // corresponding to the Source2 assigned in Velocity collection
    public String content;
    public Tag[] tags;
}
```

```
public class Tag implements Serializable {
    public String name;
    public String value;
    public String weight;
    public Attribute[] attribute;
}
```

The second part of the problem is about the consumer. I'm using Consumer Group and KafkaStream to read the data from queue. It works for primitive type, but not sure how to read the java object. Here's the code:

```
public class ConsumerGroupExample {

    private final ConsumerConnector consumer;
    private final String topic;
    private  ExecutorService executor;

    public ConsumerGroupExample(String a_zookeeper, String a_groupId, String a_topic) {
        consumer = kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(
                createConsumerConfig(a_zookeeper, a_groupId));
        this.topic = a_topic;
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        if (consumer != null) consumer.shutdown();
        if (executor != null) executor.shutdown();
        try {
            if (!executor.awaitTermination(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                System.out.println("Timed out waiting for consumer threads to shut down, exiting uncleanly");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted during shutdown, exiting uncleanly");
        }
    }

    public void run(int a_numThreads) {
        Map topicCountMap = new HashMap();
        topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(a_numThreads));
        Map>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
        List> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(a_numThreads);
        int threadNumber = 0;
        for (final KafkaStream stream : streams) {
            executor.submit(new ConsumerGroupObject(stream, threadNumber));
            threadNumber++;
        }
    }

    private static ConsumerConfig createConsumerConfig(String a_zookeeper, String a_groupId) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", a_zookeeper);
        props.put("group.id", a_groupId);
        props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "400");
        props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "200");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");

        return new ConsumerConfig(props);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String zooKeeper = args[0];
        String groupId = args[1];
        String topic = args[2];
        int threads = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

        ConsumerGroupExample example = new ConsumerGroupExample(zooKeeper, groupId, topic);
        example.run(threads);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

        }
    }
}
```

**ConsumerGroupObject**

```
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;

public class ConsumerGroupObject implements Runnable {
    private KafkaStream m_stream;
    private int m_threadNumber;

    public ConsumerGroupObject(KafkaStream a_stream, int a_threadNumber) {
        m_threadNumber = a_threadNumber;
        m_stream = a_stream;
    }

    public void run() {
        ConsumerIterator it = m_stream.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("######## Thread " + m_threadNumber + ": " + new String(it.next().message()));
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I'm trying to figure out how to extract TextAnalysisRequest object and it's nested java object through ConsumerIterator.
Sorry about the huge post, I'm new to kafka, so wanted to make sure that provide enough information.

Comment: Share your producer code snippet. The exception that you've posted occur when a object is serialized using java and de-serialized with kryo.

Comment: @KamalC .I was able to fix the first part of the problem, needed to refine the customer serializer code. I'm struggling with the second part trying to extract the output. It works if I use the following API instead of KafkaStream. 
ConsumerRecords<String, TextAnalysisRequest> records = consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);
for (ConsumerRecord<String, TextAnalysisRequest> record : records) {
{
    if(record.value()!=null){
 TextAnalysisRequest obj = record.value();
} 
This API doesn't allow the use of zookeeper in config.